# Dynamically add a participant to corda state?

Tags: blockchain, corda

I have party A, B.

I have first created a state with only A as participant for a state.

After certain actions I want to share the same state I created earlier means.

By creating a new transaction consuming the old state and creating new state by adding the Party B also, so that this state also gets stored in Party B vault or node?

Please share if you have come through like this scenario on corda.

Answer (score 3):

In Corda 3, there are several options:

- Consume the existing state, creating a new state that is identical but with `PartyB` as an added participant
- Have `PartyB` record the transaction as an observer: https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html

In Corda 4 onwards, you would add `PartyB` as one of the `sessions` to broadcast to as part of `FinalityFlow`.

Comment: Can you provide some code that demonstrates the first concept?